# I can not query with like % in collection of phalcon

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, phalcon

I use phalcon with mongo db. Model is *Collection*. 
I want use find to get

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '%TienNguyen%'
```

I see in mongo db have query

```
b.users.find(
      { Username: /TienNguyen/ }
)
```

But in collection of Phalcon. How do I code it.

I tried  `Users::find([['Username' => "/TienNguyen/"]]);`
It is not working.

Please help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with phalcon, but I think you should use phalcon regExp syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned above, regex searches that are not anchored at the beginning of the string can be very expensive because they require a full table scan. Depending on your use case you might consider using a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) instead. It provides support for case-insensitive non-anchored searches including suffix stemming.

Comment: Yes. I am finding a solutions for search data from mongo. I have a project have big data. I need analysis key search and return data. Same Google.com

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, What you wanted was the [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator form instead of passing in a `regex` as a string. While that form works in the shell, most drivers are happier with the operator syntax:

```
Users::find([[ 'Username' => [ '$regex' => 'TienNguyen' ] ]])
```

Be **very** careful using *$regex* as the page suggests. You can ruin performance if you are not searching from the**start** of the string as in `"^TienNguyen"` using the caret operator.

For reference, just JSON decode any of the standard argument forms from the Mongo manual to get your language equivalent structure for most native driver functions.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution

```
 $objs = Items::find(
        [
            [                    
                'title' => [
                    '$regex' => $query,
                    '$options' => 'i'
                ]
            ]               
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$Users = \Users::query()
            ->where(name LIKE :name:)
            ->bind(array('name' => '%' . $name . '%'))
            ->execute();
```

Comment: You only call query from model, can not call query with Collection. Thanks your help

Comment: have you tried that ? it works perfectly in a production site I am running

Comment: I do not yet. I will try it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it:

```
Users::find([['Username' => new MongoRegex("/TienNguyen/")]]);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried this but without success, it keeps returning all the documents in the collection. It seems the find function it's ignoring my parameters/conditions array. Any idea why is this happening @gabriel-bueno-lemes-da-silva ?!