# Like search into MongoDB with Monk library

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do like search into mongodb with Javascript, but i havent yet figured it out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

I have a search parameter called "search" at request body (req.body.search). I would like find all programs which name contains that search criteria. Ie. "harry" would return "**Harry** Potter", "Potter **Harry**", "How merry **Harry** Really is?" and other movies which contains harry in its name.

```
exports.programs = function(db, req) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('programs');
        collection.find({name: /req.body.search/ },{},function(e,docs){
            res.json(docs);
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can not query with like % in collection of phalcon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971727/i-can-not-query-with-like-in-collection-of-phalcon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the monk library but if the parameter in that find is a MongoDB Query Document this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
var query = {
  name: {
    $regex: req.body.search,
    $options: 'i' //i: ignore case, m: multiline, etc
  }
};

collection.find(query, {}, function(e,docs){});
```

Chekcout [MongoDB $regex Documentaiton](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).