# How do you perform a Case-Insensitive query in node.js implementations of mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have a collection containing usernames. If a user searches for "joe", I want it to return "Joe", and any case-different variants (i.e. "jOe", etc.).

I'm using monk to implement mongodb queries in my node.js application - but the documentation has no mention of case insensitive queries, nor does it have any implementation of collations.

I am aware that regex can be used (and works), but it seems to go against the advice of the mongo documentation. Is there a regexless way of doing this in node.js implementations of MongoDB?

I'm unsure as to how I would implement a query like this - Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query. Lots of options in the answers there.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021576/like-search-into-mongodb-with-monk-library may help you

Comment: HI, yes - I've seen these posts and they don't work formally with **node.js** implementations of mongoDB (namely monk - but also mongoose), as they don't have implementations for collations. The remaining option is regex, which is against mongoDB's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB supports [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) - as long as the field has the appropriate [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) you can leverage the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator which supports a `caseSensitive` option.